# Error file not found fontlist-v300.json during import of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Software    Version
Python  3.5.6 64bit [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython 6.5.0
OS  Windows 8.1 6.3.9600 SP0
numpy   1.15.2
scipy   1.1.0
matplotlib  3.0.0

I encounter the following error when importing matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\PAUL\\.matplotlib\\fontlist-v300.json'
```

Comment: This should be fixed in matplotlib 3.0.2. You can directly update to 3.0.3 by now.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the recent update of the [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12173/), you could try update matplotlib to `3.0.1/3.0.2` (also as suggested by ImportanceOfBeingErnest). But people still reporting the problems persists, so the bug might still in works.

From my personal experience, I installed old version of matplotlib that currently works with my work, which is `2.2.3`. You could try this option, and match it with your current Python environments

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to the latest version of matplotlib. I had a similar problem. fixed it by upgrading to `3.0.3`

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```